# Match any character in a regexp (e.g. `string-match`)

Tags: regular-expressions

In perl when matching multi-line strings you can add the `s` modifier `/.../s` that will change the semantics of `.` to match also newline. Is there something similar for `string-match`? Or is there a workaround?

Comment: Are you asking for a way to convert regular expressions that have `.` to additionally match new lines or how to match any character including newline in general?

Comment: FWIW, I asked that this ability be added to Elisp regexps long ago: [1](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2006-03/msg00162.html) and [2](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2006-11/msg01504.html). Went nowhere...

Comment: @Drew: For the perl `m` modifier I can used instead of `^` and `$`  the escaped  `` \\` `` and `` \' ``  (hard to write in markdown). But for ```.``` it doesnt seem to exist. Feels indeed like something that would be helpful if added. Phils answer below does work. I tried before with `[[:asci:][:nonascii]]` but stangely that failes if there is a unicode sequence embedded in the textstream anyway.

Comment: Yes, @phils's answer is what we have to do (and have always had to do): specify "either a newline char or a char other than newline". My comment was to point out that I think Elisp regexps should offer a short way of specifying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't make `.` match newlines; you have to simply state what you want to match.  e.g.: `"\\(?:.\\|\n\\)"`

However if you use `rx` to generate your regexp, then note that it provides distinct symbols for the two cases:

```
`not-newline', `nonl'
     matches any character except a newline.

`anything'
     matches any character
```

e.g.:

```
(rx "foo" anything "bar")
=> "foo\\(?:.\\|
\\)bar"
```